# Do you know how to fix this UPDATE issue?

Tags: sql

When this code runs, I get an UPDATE writing error. Does anybody know what the problem is, and how to fix it?

This is the code:

```
string sql2 = "UPDATE ezuser";
sql2 += " SET fname = '" + Request.Form["fname"]+ "'";
sql2 += " , lname = '" + Request.Form["lname"] + "'";
sql2 += " , fav = '" + Request.Form["fav"] + "'";
sql2 += " , pw = '" + Request.Form["pw"] + "'";
sql2 += " , order = '" + Request.Form["order"] + "'";
sql2 += " WHERE email = '" + Request.Form["email"] + "'";

MyAdoHelper.DoQuery(fileName, sql2);
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough the question doesnt tell me much about the datatypes of columns, the only thing I could suspect here is the order column, which might be of integer datatype and you might be passing string to that.

Additional note: your code looks very much vulnerable to sql injections. Please take a look into that as well.

Answer (score 0):

At least in SQL Server, `order` is a reserved keyword and needs to properly quoted if used literally as a column name. Like so:

```
sql2 += " , [order] = '" + Request.Form["order"] + "'";
```

As sabhari already mentioned, you need to learn about SQL Injection and how to properly guard against that. Research parametrized statements for the programming language you are using.

Comment: @AmitAlmog You're welcome. Do me a favor, and click the checkmark next to this answer (that would help me in return).